# How can I change audio position on click with Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, audio, web

Im trying to make various buttons that will change the position (right/left) of an audio file when they are clicked.  The first audio "wind" works fine. It plays on click and changes position based on which button is pushed. However, the second audio "churchbells" doesn't change position.  Im really unsure how this all works, so I tried changing the name of each thing to give it a unique identifier, but it doesnt work.

```js
  <script>
 

let audioContext = new AudioContext();

// Create a (1st-order Ambisonic) Songbird scene.
let songbird = new Songbird(audioContext);

// Send songbird's binaural output to stereo out.
songbird.output.connect(audioContext.destination);

// Set room acoustics properties.
let dimensions = {
  width : 4,
  height : 2.5,
  depth : 3
};
let materials = {
  left : 'plaster-rough',
  right : 'plaster-rough',
  front : 'plaster-rough',
  back : 'plaster-rough',
  down : 'plywood-panel',
  up : 'plaster-rough'
};
songbird.setRoomProperties(dimensions, materials);

// Create an audio element. Feed into audio graph.
let audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.src = 'wind.ogg';


let audioElementSource =
  audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

// Create a Source, connect desired audio input to it.
let source = songbird.createSource();
audioElementSource.connect(source.input);


// The source position is relative to the origin
// (center of the room).
source.setPosition(0.0, 8.9, 0);

// Playback the audio.
function wind() {
 
audioElement.play();
audioElement.loop = true;

}


function right1() {
source.setPosition(-0.9, 8.9, 0);
}
function right2() {
source.setPosition(-2, 8.9, -1);
}
function right3() {
source.setPosition(-1, 8.9, -2);
}
function right4() {
source.setPosition(0, 8.9, -3);
}
function right5() {
source.setPosition(1, 8.9, -2);
}
function right6() {
source.setPosition(2, 8.9, -1);
}
function right7() {
source.setPosition(0.9, 8.9, 0);
}
function right8() {
source.setPosition(0, 8.9, 0);
}


  </script>
  
<!-- Church Bell -->
  <script>

let audioContext1 = new AudioContext();

// Create a (1st-order Ambisonic) Songbird scene.
let songbird1 = new Songbird(audioContext1);

// Send songbird's binaural output to stereo out.
songbird1.output.connect(audioContext1.destination);

// Set room acoustics properties.
let dimensions = {
  width : 4,
  height : 2.5,
  depth : 3
};
let materials = {
  left : 'plaster-rough',
  right : 'plaster-rough',
  front : 'plaster-rough',
  back : 'plaster-rough',
  down : 'plywood-panel',
  up : 'plaster-rough'
};
songbird1.setRoomProperties(dimensions, materials);

// Create an audio element. Feed into audio graph.
 
let audioElement1 = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement1.src = 'churchbells.ogg';


let audioElementSource1 =
  audioContext1.createMediaElementSource(audioElement1);

// Create a Source, connect desired audio input to it.
let source1 = songbird1.createSource();
audioElementSource1.connect(source1.input);

// The source position is relative to the origin
// (center of the room).
source1.setPosition(-99, 8.9, 0);
function churchbells() {
// Playback the audio.
audioElement1.play(); 
}
function churchbellsright1() {

source1.setPosition(99, 8.9, 0);
}

  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/songbird/master/build/songbird.js"></script>

    <button onclick="play();">play</button>

    <button onclick="right1();">right 1</button>
    <button onclick="right2();">right 2</button>
    <button onclick="right3();">right 3</button>
    <button onclick="right4();">right 4</button>
    <button onclick="right5();">right 5</button>
    <button onclick="right6();">right 6</button>
    <button onclick="right7();">right 7</button>
    <button onclick="right8();">right 8</button>
    <button onclick="churchbellsright1();">right 8</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the functions `right1`, `right2` etc inside the `play` function. That means they will not be available to the `onclick` handler. Anything defined inside a function is only available in that function. So you need to define them outside the `play` function.

You also need to declare `source` outside that function so the `right1` functions will have access to it. Try something like this:

```
// declare source outside of play
let source;

function play() {
  // Start of the play() code

  // Assign songbird.createSource() to the source variable we already declared
  source = songbird.createSource();
  audioElementSource.connect(source.input);

  // The rest of the play() code
}

function right1() {
  source.setPosition(-0.9, 8.9, 0);
}
// define right2, right3, etc here.
```

Comment: That did make it work, thanks.  However, I realized that the second audio I have doesn't work in the same way. I updated my original question with the code.  Im pretty new to this so im not sure how to approach this.  I tried changing all the names in the second audio (churchbells) to give it a unique identifier (source1 vs source, audioelement1 vs audioelement etc..), but it doesnt work. If I put the churchbells function at the top it plays the audio, but doesnt change position. When its placed like it is in the code neither audio nor position works.  Any idea how to make more than one work?

Comment: Creating another copy of this with a different name for `source`, `play`, and `right1` etc should work. Here's a quick sample I came up with that plays two at a time: https://gist.github.com/tfogo/b80a3e4ea184c0c653f0ee1b1349a4dc It returns the source from `play()` so you can call it with different music files and you can assign it to different variables. It's not the cleanest code but it works. It's better to make your functions reusable instead of copying them over and over with slightly different contents.

Comment: It looks like that worked. Thanks so much man, i'm very relieved, I didnt know how I was gonna get past that problem.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help. :)